# How do these different expressions of the Jaccard similarity coefficient relate?

Tags: jaccard-similarity

I am aware the Jaccard similarity coefficient, $J$, is classically defined as the cardinality of the intersection divided by the cardinality of the union of two sets, $A$ and $B$.  I can easily understand and comprehend this equation.

$$J=\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A \cup B|}=\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|}$$

However, I have also come across another expression for the Jaccard similarity coefficient using vector data, $p$ and $q$, instead of sets (see, for example, page 302, Equation 22 in [Cha 2007](https://pdodds.w3.uvm.edu/research/papers/others/2007/cha2007a.pdf))

$$J=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i q_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n q_i^2 -\sum_{i=1}^n p_i q_i}$$

This expression is not as obvious to me in terms of assessing the similarity between the vectors. I have been trying to find a reference that shows how expression for vector data is derived and how that relates to the set theoretic expression of the Jaccard similarity coefficient - but without any luck. Any help or suggestions welcome.

Reference: Cha, S-H. (2007). Comprehensive Survey on Distance/Similarity Measures between Probability Density Functions. Journal of Mathematical Models and Methods in Applied Sciences, 4:300-307.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the vectors contain zeros or ones and refer to two sets being compared.

$p_i$ or $q_i$ is $1$ if element $i$ is in one set or another and $0$ otherwise.

Then $\sum p_i^2$ is the total number of elements in the first set (and
incidentally it is equal to $\sum p_i$ as $1^2 = 1$). $\sum q_i^2$ is to be interpreted in the same way for the second set.

Each $p_i q_i$ is $1$ if and only if both $p_i$ and $q_i$ are $1$. Otherwise it is $0$, for all three cases $p_i = 0, q_i = 0; p_i = 1, q_i = 0; p_i = 0, q_i = 1$. So $\sum p_i q_i$ counts the number of elements in the intersection of the two sets.

I don't have a reference and don't recall seeing Jaccard defined in this way, but it would be natural enough as a step towards code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added a reference to the question (there are many more I have). Also I am not sure the vectors are limited to zeros and ones as this applies to probability density functions, hence they would be unit vectors (as implied in reference).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Sorry, but I don't now have the time or inclination to study it closely. But clearly if $p$ can have values other than $0$ or $1$, then it's no longer true that (e.g.) $\sum p_i = \sum p_i^2$.